# How can I add expired token in auth nuxt js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I try like this in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      home: '/home',
      logout: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: "refresh",
        token: {
          property: 'access_token',
          maxAge: 900,
          // type: 'Bearer'
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: "refresh_token",
          data: "refresh_token",
          maxAge: 60 * 15
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'response.token'
          },
          user: false,
          logout: false
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer '
      }
    },
    token: {
      name: 'token'
    },
    cookie: {
      name: 'token'
    }
},
```

I set 15 minutes, but after 15 minutes, I still automatically log in
How can I solve this problem?

Reference : https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh.html#options

Comment: Are you sure the refresh API isn't being called after 15 mins when you try to login? Can you please check the network tab of the developers tool for once to confirm this?

Comment: @Helper I want to make sure 1 thing. It's about the value of property and data. It should `refreshToken: { property: "refresh_token", data: "refresh_token", maxAge: 60 * 15 },` Or `refreshToken: { property: "response.token", data: "response.token", maxAge: 60 * 15 }` ?

Comment: That sir, depends on the structure of data that you're receiving from the server. property: 'access_token' means that the data must have a structure something like this: {access_token: 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN'}, whereas { property: "response.token"} means that the structure is going to be something like this: {"response": {token: "YOUR TOKEN"}}

Comment: @Helper  Okay thanks. For your first question, can you screenshot on the network tab, which part shows it?

Comment: @Helper Please screenshot it. I want to see that